# Excel count rows where column B equals value and value in column A is not a duplicate

Tags: excel

I have a table as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | happy |
| 1 | sad |
| 2 | angry |
| 2 | sad |
| 3 | sad |
| 4 | moody |
| 4 | thoughtful |
| 5 | excited |

I need to count the number of times "sad" appears in column B whose value in column A is NOT a duplicate.

I am aware of  =COUNTIF(B2:B8, "sad") but I'm stuck there.

Our answer should be 1 since sad only occurs once without a duplicate in A.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SuMPRODUCT with a COUNTIFS():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="Sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: and what would I do if I also want to count the amount of times "sad" has a duplicate in A? Doing =SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="Sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1)) gives me the wrong result (expected 2)

Comment: New questions get new posts.

Comment: New question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771311/excel-count-rows-where-column-b-equals-value-and-value-in-column-a-is-a-duplicat