# Excel count rows where column B and C equals value and value in column A is a duplicate

Tags: excel

I have a table as follows:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | happy | 1-veggies |
| 1 | sad | 1-veggies |
| 2 | angry | 2-meat |
| 2 | sad | 2-meat |
| 3 | sad | 2-veggies |
| 4 | moody | 2-meat |
| 4 | thoughtful | 2-meat |
| 5 | excited | 2-meat |

I need to count the number of times "sad" appears in column B whose value in column C is veggies and the number in column A is a duplicate.

Our answer should be 1 since sad occurs once with a duplicate in A and 1-veggies in column C.

However, IF the data set changes and there are no 1-veggies, the answer should return 0, not #N/A

Thank you.

Comment: the formula you proposed in the comments to my last answer: `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="Sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1))` works for me.

Comment: not for me, it multiplies by several foctors when the dat set is expanded

Comment: Then you will need to show the data for which it does not work, because it works with the data set you provided.

Comment: As you can see the answer below returns `0` not `#N/A` where there are no `Veggies`.   I do not see how you are getting that with the dataset you are providing.  There is more to this picture than you are giving.

Comment: No, there literally isn't. I can't explain it

Comment: do your have formulas that return errors in your dataset?  If there are errors in the third column then it would return an error.

Comment: nope, non are formulas

Comment: BTW: you should judge the answer on the data set given and not your real data if you are not posting the real data.  As it sits the answer below answers your question with the data and requirements given.  It did not deserve a down vote.

Comment: Post a picture of the data set and how you used the formula below that is returning the `#N/A` we need something that we can replicate.  we cannot replicate it with what you have given.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it doesn't answer the question since my dataset, as provided is producing this error on your answer.

Comment: I need to see a photo, there is something different than on your dataset than mine.

Comment: one question, You are using `SUMPRODUCT` and not `SUM`?  If you use `SUM()` then depending on your version you may need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="Sad")*(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("veggies",C1:C8))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it multiplies by several factors when the dat set is expanded

Comment: I'm seeing errors where if the table doesn't contain any "veggies" I see #N/A. Is there a way of handling that error?

Comment: how many questions are you going to try and squeeze into this one? @Sweepster.  It is not Axuary's issue you cannot ask a complete question.

Comment: @axuary Since the OP edited the question I edited your answer to match. I built on your start. If you do not like it, feel free to roll it back. There was no sense answering on my own part.

Comment: The funnny thing about answers is that they raise new problems. This is literally the same question I asked in OP. If there is an error introduced by your answer, how is it handled?

Comment: No, Your original question did not even have the third column.  Then you did not talk about what to do when there are none.  But I doubt that is the issue, my guess is that you have errors in the data.  The SUMPRODUCT should return `0` if there are no `Veggies` in the third column not `#N/A` @Sweepster

Comment: For proof on the `0` see the new picture I just posted. @Sweepster

Comment: If I do =SUMPRODUCT(B1:B8="Sad")*SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A1:A8)>1)*SUMPRODUCT(C1:C8="veggies") then it returns 0 but if I put it as you did, I get #N/A

Comment: @Sweepster show me a photo.  I showed you one proving it to work.  I need one showing me that it does not.

Comment: urgh, you're right, the issue is my veggies are actually "1-veggies" and hyphen seems to be causing the issue

Comment: That should still return `0` not `#N/A` @Sweepster